# How can I add a record field to sorted SQL results?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, rank

I'm trying to add a record number field to sorted SQL results table but I'm not getting the result I'm after.

Here's a results table properly sorted by `id` but without the record number field:

```
SELECT id, SeriesName
  FROM tvseries 
 WHERE SeriesName LIKE '%certain-tv-show%'
 ORDER BY id ASC;

+--------+------------+
| id     | SeriesName |
+--------+------------+
|  77092 | Series1    |
|  79395 | Series2    |
|  79949 | Series3    |
|  80341 | Series4    |
| 203581 | Series5    |
| 242521 | Series6    |
| 250374 | Series7    |
| 252679 | Series8    |
| 269228 | Series9    |
| 271452 | Series10   |
| 274997 | Series11   |
| 292986 | Series12   |
| 293986 | Series13   |
| 307475 | Series14   |
| 319215 | Series15   |
+--------+------------+
```

Below is an attempt to add a record number field to the same results table as above.  However, the `ORDER BY id ASC` clause seems to be ignored as the results are similar to what I get when not ordering the results (not shown anywhere as it would be duplicated below barring the record number field):

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as Num, Results.* 
  FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
       (SELECT id, SeriesName from tvseries 
         WHERE SeriesName LIKE '%certain-tv-show%'
         ORDER BY id ASC) Results;

+------+--------+------------+
| Num  | id     | SeriesName |
+------+--------+------------+
|    1 |  77092 | Series1    |
|    2 |  79395 | Series2    |
|    3 |  79949 | Series3    |
|    4 |  80341 | Series4    |
|    5 | 319215 | Series15   |
|    6 | 203581 | Series5    |
|    7 | 242521 | Series6    |
|    8 | 250374 | Series7    |
|    9 | 252679 | Series8    |
|   10 | 269228 | Series9    |
|   11 | 271452 | Series10   |
|   12 | 274997 | Series11   |
|   13 | 307475 | Series14   |
|   14 | 292986 | Series12   |
|   15 | 293986 | Series13   |
+------+--------+------------+
```

The "DOCTORED" results below is what I'm hoping to accomplish from within MySQL:

`+------+--------+------------+
| Num  | id     | SeriesName |
+------+--------+------------+
|    1 |  77092 | Series1    |
|    2 |  79395 | Series2    |
|    3 |  79949 | Series3    |
|    4 |  80341 | Series4    |
|    5 | 203581 | Series5    |
|    6 | 242521 | Series6    |
|    7 | 250374 | Series7    |
|    8 | 252679 | Series8    |
|    9 | 269228 | Series9    |
|   10 | 271452 | Series10   |
|   11 | 274997 | Series11   |
|   12 | 292986 | Series12   |
|   13 | 293986 | Series13   |
|   14 | 307475 | Series14   |
|   15 | 319215 | Series15   |
+------+--------+------------+`

I'm trying this in MariaDB 10.0.29 which leads me to think it isn't possible in any version of either MariaDB or MySQL.  A colleague suggested I look at stored procedures but I'm a hobbyist DBA and that would be beyond me.

EDIT:

@GordonLinoff: Thanks for your answer.  If I need to employ your solution to a more complex query, how would I go about it:

```
SELECT sea.season as Season, ep.EpisodeNumber as Episode, ep.EpisodeName as Title
FROM tvseasons sea
INNER JOIN tvepisodes ep on ep.seasonid = sea.id
INNER JOIN tvseries ser on ser.id = ep.seriesid
WHERE ser.id = 'some_id' AND Season != 0
ORDER BY Season,Episode ASC;
```

EDIT2:
I've modified my query as follows:

```
SELECT ($rn := $rn + 1) AS Num, sea.season AS Season, ep.EpisodeNumber AS Episode, ep.EpisodeName AS Title
  FROM tvseasons sea
 INNER JOIN tvepisodes ep on ep.seasonid = sea.id
 INNER JOIN tvseries ser on ser.id = ep.seriesid
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT $rn := 0) params 
 WHERE ser.id = 'some_id' AND Season != 0
 ORDER BY Season,Episode ASC;
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':= $rn + 1) AS Num, sea.season AS Season, ep.EpisodeNumber AS Episode, ep.Episod' at line 1
```

Ideas for the clueless?

EDIT3:
In addition, I believe the `CROSS JOIN` is actually what makes the difference.  To see it in full context (and hopefully I'm allowed to post links): [Querying The TVDB](https://pastebin.com/Sqm2iaam)

EDIT4:
I didn't realize I had swapped out `@` for `$` - thanks for the heads up - all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as num, t.id, t.SeriesName
FROM tvseries t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
WHERE t.SeriesName LIKE '%certain-tv-show%'
ORDER BY t.id ASC;
```

I do think that your query should also work.

Comment: Yes, this works as expected; not sure why my query doesn't work.  I'd really like to expand my knowledge of SQL queries as I have no clue what that `cross join` did but it obviously solved my problem.  Book suggestion? Will mark this as the answer as soon as I verify it works for a few queries with large result sets.

Comment: @AnthonyK . . . I don't think `CROSS JOIN` solved your problem.  In this context, it is the same as a comma.  I just abhor commas in the `FROM` clause, and I am explicit about the `JOIN` type.

Comment: Please also see the edit to my question.  I need to test on a larger result set but don't have a clue on how to stitch the `cross join` to my `inner joins`.

Comment: @AnthonyK . . . You can put at the beginning or end of the `FROM` clause . . . ` CROSS JOIN ( . . . ) params`.

Comment: @AnthonyK . . . `$rn` <> `@rn`.

Comment: @AnthonyK . . . I'm curious why you unaccepted the answer.

Comment: Sorry to have to revoke the answer, but it doesn't work on long sorted list... see this https://pastebin.com/gWS5bzWV